# Need help in updating resource tags using python sdk in AZURE

Tags: azure, azure-python-sdk

I am looking for help in updating the resource tags using python SDK in azure. I am able to update tags for `resource groups` but I am not able to find how I can update tags for `resources`

Below is the code that I have used for updating `resource groups` tags

```
from azure.identity import AzureCliCredential
from azure.mgmt.resource import ResourceManagementClient
import os
credential = AzureCliCredential()

subscription_id = os.environ["AZURE_SUBSCRIPTION_ID"] = "Key"

#resource_group = os.getenv("RESOURCE_GROUP_NAME", "name")

resource_client = ResourceManagementClient(credential, subscription_id)

group_list = resource_client.resources.list()


for group in list(group_list):
    a = group.location
    b = group.name
    if not group.tags:
        resource_client.resources.create_or_update(
                b,
                {
                    "location" : a,
                    "tags" : tag_dict
                }
        )
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on your requirement , we have written the below code to create the tags to the individual resources under a particular resource group
We have tested the code in our local environment  & it is working fine.

```html
    from  logging  import  NullHandler
    from  azure.core  import  pipeline
    from  azure.identity  import  AzureCliCredential,  _credentials
    from  azure.mgmt.resource  import  ResourceManagementClient,  resources
    import  os
    
    credential  =  AzureCliCredential()
    subscription_id  =  "<subscription-id>"
    resource_group  =  "<resource-group>"
    resource_client  =  ResourceManagementClient(credential,  subscription_id)
    resource_list=  resource_client.resources.list_by_resource_group(resource_group)
    tag_dict  =  {"Month":  "sept-24"}
    for  resource  in  resource_list:
      body  =  {
        "operation"  :  "create",
         "properties"  :  {
            "tags"  :  tag_dict
          }
     }  
      resource_client.tags.create_or_update_at_scope(resource.id,body)
    print("Resource tags were updated successfully please check the output in the portal")
```

Here is the Sample output for reference:

[image]